# Paypal sandbox testing payment not allowing test buyer mail and password

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use Paypal sandbox API for testing a simple payment process. I created 2 accounts - merchant & buyer. Then I created a web app having the jsp as below -

```
<body onload="document.forms['paypalForm'].submit();">
<form name="paypalForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value=<API Username> />  
<input type="hidden" name="password" value=<API Password> />  
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1123" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Computer-Laptop" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost:8084/DemoPaypalApi/paypalResponse.jsp" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost:8084/DemoPaypalApi/paypalResponseCancel.jsp" />
<input type="hidden" name="cert_id" value=<Signature> />     
</form>
</body>
```

API Username, API Password & Signature have been pasted from my account on https://developer.paypal.com

On running the app, i get redirected to the paypal sandbox UI. However on entering the buyer mail id & password I keep getting "Please make sure you have entered your email address correctly" and "Please re-enter your PayPal password" errors.

Need your help.

Answer (score 0):

hmm not sure where you picked up the code but it's very insecure - please don't pass APIUsername/APIPassword/Signature through a Web Form in a browser.

If you can provide a little bit more info on what you are trying to do I can suggest the best way to implement it.

Comment: This is just a demo code. It may not be proper from design perspective. However the issue is that its not working. i.e. the test account for buyer is not logging in.

Comment: The 'username' you're supplying to log in with should be in the form of an 'email address'. That is, it should follow the mailbox@domain.tld structure. Is that what you're using? You're certain you're on www.sandbox.paypal.com and not www.paypal.com?